# Build a named route with params in the Blade templating engine with Laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a route:

```
Route::get('/admin/users/manage/{id}', 'Admin\UsersController@manage')->name('admin.users.manage');
```

Then in my blade file I'm looping over the users and outputting information as well as a link to the above route.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ $user->id }}</th>
    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{ route('admin.users.manage', ['id' => $user->id]) }} " class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I get the following error:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.users.manage] [URI: admin/users/manage/{id}]. (View: /resources/views/layouts/partials/admin/_sidebar.blade.php) (View: /resources/views/layouts/partials/admin/_sidebar.blade.php)
```

I have tried doing it without the escaping as well but the same error occurs.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ $user->id }}</th>
    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="{!! route('admin.users.manage', ['id' => $user->id]) !!} " class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove some [], see below

```
<td>
    <a href="{{ route('admin.users.manage', $user->id) }} " class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <a href="{!! route('admin.users.manage', [$user->id]) !!} " class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

if you use Associative array it will compiled as

```
/admin/users/manage/{id}?id=id
```

If you want use only [$user->id] it will be compiled as actual parameter of the route.

```
/admin/users/manage/$id
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can even remove the [] parts as not needed, you can just use $user->id